# Multiple CTA buttons (same link) in Email marketing?

Tags: usability, buttons, email, marketing, cta

Thoughts on having the *same* CTA appear twice in a short marketing email?

One is in the main image (the whole thing is essentially clickable) and the second is after some copy on the bottom.

They both are the same buttons that click off to the same page. Marketing thinks we need more, my intuition makes me think less is more.

Comment: You should provide an illustration to get a more concise response. Everything depends context.

Comment: If you sent a version with both buttons, can you report back what your metrics told you with an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if two CTAs remain visually identical and perform the same action then there is nothing wrong. This may increase the chance of clicking but should be done cautiously.

P.S. Try to limit 1 CTA per view.

Use case: I have seen Netflix doing this. But it has been removed now.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image look like it is clickable/tappable?

Are both CTA buttons visible at the same time?

Without too much context:

I think it's fine to have **both visible**, specially if the user scrolls, that way they'll have a way to navigate to you target URL

Answer (score 0):

Two buttons are basically more agresive way to "Call people to action" therefore it could result in having more clicks.
Nevertheless user purchase or conversion depends also on motivation and other factors and it is question does having 2 instead of 1 button will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Possibilities.

**Possibility 1**:

If your main image explains everything about your email content with graphics and a short title. Then you can use CTA in Image and make a clickable image, which redirects to particular any destination or to your goal. Then it is fine to CTA in Image.

**Possibility 2**:

If your email content is very long and the user not able to see the second CTA on a single screen view, then it's fine to put 2 CTA in the Email.